# Using Lua with SQL, why to use partition by clause

Tags: sql, lua

I have this SQL statement in my lua program :

```
k = conn:query({ live=true, 
                 sql="select ReportBody 
                      from OrderReports 
                      where OrderId= '"..T.OrderId.."'"})
```

In above statement I need to use Order By clause , but the error says it is not allowed to use order by clause with views, so I used this query:

```
k = conn:query({live = true, 
                sql= "select ReportBody,
                      DENSE_RANK() over (Order by ModifyDate DESC) 
                      from OrderReports 
                      where OrderId = '"..T.OrderId.."'"})
```

but I have seen Partition by being used almost all the times with the `dense_rank()` function, so i need to understand what difference it will make here if I use Partition by and what that is for ?

Comment: Essentially, `PARTITION BY` is telling whatever OLAP function you're using (here, `DENSE_RANK()`) when to start over.  Its largely equivalent to a `GROUP BY`, except you still get all the individual rows.  Note that, officially, the order you get rows back in is _not_ guaranteed to be from the OLAP's `ORDER BY` clause - that's just a common side effect of using it.  Why does this generate a view?   I'm not familiar with Lua, but this looks like it might be open to SQL Injection - is there a way to do parameterized queries?